# How can I instantiate a class with statically declared arrays of different sizes?

Tags: c++

I'd like to create a class with a statically declared array. I'd like to extend the class that basically changes the size of the array in the derived class. Everything else would stay the same.

```
namespace someNameSpace {
   const uint8_t STATIC_ARRAY_SIZE = 50; // <-- change this value in a derived class?
   class BaseClass {
       private:
          int some_array[STATIC_ARRAY_SIZE];
       public:
          void some_function_that_uses_above_array(){ ... };
   }
}
```

Is there a way to do this without using templating? (I need the arrays to be allocated memory at compile time).

Comment: I'm assuming that the derived class needs to keep the contents of the original array? Could you not just do a copy into a larger array when you construct the derived class? Also, it would be better if you posted the full example so I can have a better idea on what you mean.

Comment: The contents of the array are empty initially. They get populated with various functions from the base class. Basically I want to instantiate many different versions of this class and each one has different array sizes that are statically declared...

Answer (score 0):

You can use template meta-programming for this:

```
namespace someNameSpace {
    template <size_t STATIC_ARRAY_SIZE>
    class BaseClass {
    private:
        int some_array[STATIC_ARRAY_SIZE];
    public:
        void some_function_that_uses_above_array(){ ... };
    }

    class Derived : public BaseClass<42> {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: There's not much going on here in the way of "meta-programming".  The compiler doesn't really compute much - it just decides on the size of the array.  I would describe this as just _using a template_.

Comment: I use `STATIC_ARRAY_SIZE` as a way of making sure I don't overflow on that array. I.e with `some_num % STATIC_ARRAY_SIZE`. Since modulo is an expensive operation, it helps to use `uint32_t` in some cases. However in some cases I need a `uint64_t`. Is there a way to template with both the size and the value?

Comment: Programming with templates has nothing to do with template meta programming. You simply use a single template parameter, there is really no program! And you should remark that you get the code for the class in your binary for every new value which is maybe not what OP expects.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to allocated at compile time, it is mean not dinamically allocated i think the solution you want still is template. At compile time for each different template parameter the compiler will generate a copy of class.

Example:

With @sturcotte06 code, if you declare in someplace BaseClass<10> or BaseClass<20>, for each parameter 10 and 20, the compiler will copy the code of class and apply the parameter like a #define.
In [this link](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/257589/An-Idiots-Guide-to-Cplusplus-Templates-Part-1) search for "PrintTwice function with int and double", there is a pratical example.

If you can't use template because of restrictions, i don't recommend but you can pass the array through constructor as a smart pointer, to avoid null reference is important check pointer on costructor and take a care on destructor.